# Getting data in database format from excel file [Python]

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I have a Table in Excel that has this structure:

| Country | County | 20/01/2020 | 21/01/2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country | County | Value 1 | Value 2 |

I would like to be able to convert the table into the following format so that I could add it in a table in my database.

| Country | County | Date | Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country | County | 20/01/2020 | Value 1 |
| Country | County | 20/01/2020 | Value 2 |

Is there a quick way to do this or should I iterate over each row and create a dataframe from there? The excel file has millions of entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.melt` is what you're looking for:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['Country','County'], var_name = 'Date')
```

supply the dataframe as the first argument, then id_vars tells the function which columns you want to keep for each row. the rest of the columns will be turned into values in a new column in the melted dataframe. then var_name says what you want that new column to be called.

Comment: If you want the new column to be treated the same way as Country & County, then yes. If you want it treated the same as the 'date' columns, you wouldn't need to change anything.

Comment: Perfect thank you i edited the question because as soon as I typed it I just gave it a try and saw how it worked. Thank you again for your time!